# Remove corrupt windows from laptop and install new windows again using linux

Tags: linux, windows, disk, reinstall

A few days ago, i changed a files in the windows directory using debian. After that it would cause kernel panic in my windows os. Is there any way to install new windows on the same corrupt disk partition ?? Please help me..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Windows, not Unix / Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert your windows disk and then do manual partitioning and choose to install ONLY that partition, but I think you'll have with the grub, and then you will need to repair it with a live, in any case, before you do anything you do a backup of data